# How to replace bidirectional OneToOne relation by ElementCollection?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, embeddable

"**Java Persistence 2.0, Final Release**" on page 404 has the following example:

Example 3: One-to-one association from an embeddable class to another entity.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id int id;
  @Embedded LocationDetails location;
...
}

@Embeddable
public class LocationDetails {
  int officeNumber;
  @OneToOne ParkingSpot parkingSpot;
...
}

@Entity
 public class ParkingSpot {
  @Id int id;
  String garage;
  @OneToOne(mappedBy="location.parkingSpot") Employee assignedTo;
...
}
```

I would like to have multiple LocationDetails inside Employee:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id int id;
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name="EMP_LOCATION") 
  Map<String, LocationDetails> locations;
...
}
```

How the entity ParkingSpot has to be changed to point back to embeddable LocationDetails inside the collection table EMP_LOCATION.

Should be

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="location.parkingSpot") Employee assignedTo;
```

replaced be by @ElementCollection ?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer in the book: "[Keith M., Schincariol M. - Pro JPA 2, 2nd Edition (The Expert's Voice in Java) - 2013](http://www.apress.com/9781430249269?gtmf=s)" page 271.

> A proviso about embeddable types is that if an embedded object is a
>   part of an element collection, then the embedded object in the
>   collection **can only include mappings where the foreign key is stored
>   in the source table**. It can contain owned relationships, such as
>   one-to-one and many-to-one, but it cannot contain one-to-many or
>   many-to-many relationships where the foreign key is in either the
>   target table or a join table. Similarly, it can’t contain other
>   collection table-based mappings like element collections.

The solution would be to have LocationDetails as an entity, rather then an embedded object.